# Accessing derived class variables in base class function in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am writing some code that share a lot of functionality, ideally I will have 10+ derived class, the derived class will define its own parameters, then you may call the derived class `process` function, and the process will use the derived class function (they all have the same code) but using the derived class as inputs, ie.

```
#include <iostream>
class base
{
public:
    base() {}
    void print_coef() { std::cout << "base :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }
private:
    int coef;
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    derived1() { coef = 420; }
    void print() { std::cout << "derived :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }
private:   
    int coef;
};

int main(void)
{
    derived1 test;
    test.print_coef();
    test.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
base :: coef is: 1
derived :: coef is: 420
```

I want it to be both 420, how can I make the coefficients in derived available to base?

Comment: *I want it to be both 420* - don't declare the second `int coef;`

Comment: Learn about [shadowing](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/variable-shadowing-name-hiding/) to know why your code is not working

Comment: You seem to be under the misapprehension that you need to declare `coef` in both `base` and `derived1`.  You don't, just in `base` will do (and mark it `protected`).

Answer (score 0):

`base::coef` and `derived1::coef` are two separate variables, where the latter is *shadowing* the former.

`base::print_coef()` only knows about `base::coef`, it has no knowledge of `derived1::coef`.

`derived1::print()` knows about and has access to `derived1::coef`, and it can know about `base::coef`, but has no access to it because it is `private` to `base`.

To do what you are attempting, get rid of `derived1::coef` and make `base::coef` be `protected` instead of `private` so `derived1` can access it, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
    base() {}
    void print_coef() { std::cout << "base :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }
protected:
    int coef;
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    derived1() { coef = 420; }
    void print() { std::cout << "derived :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    derived1 test;
    test.print_coef();
    test.print();
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/E651Y3)

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class base {
   public:
    base() {}
    // initialise base coefficient
    base(int i) : coef(i) {}
    void print_coef() { std::cout << "base :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }

   private:
    int coef;

   protected:
    // give read access to children
    int getcoef() const { return coef; }
};

class derived1 : public base {
   public:
    derived1() : base(420) {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "derived :: coef is: " << getcoef() << std::endl;
    }
    // KO do not redeclare a parent member variable
    // private:
    //     int coef;
};

int main(void) {
    derived1 test;
    test.print_coef();
    test.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I have removed `derived1::coef` class because redeclaring a member variable in children ([shadowing](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/variable-shadowing-name-hiding)) is, as far as I know, always a bad idea (according to what kind of pointer you use (pointer to base or pointer to derived), you may not access what you think).
Remember, as @Remy Lebeau said, that the base class does not know about its children members.
Besides I prefer not using `protected` on member variables as you should not trust what the children will do with them.
I control what the children can do by giving them an API (using public or protected functions).

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by deleting the variable from derived class, and making it protected on base class

```
class base
{
public:
    base() {}
    void print_coef() { std::cout << "base :: coef is: " << coef << std::endl; }
protected:
    int coef;
};
```